# Difference between "define-key global-map" and "global-set-key" in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Looking at how people program their keyboard shortcuts in Emacs, I have noticed two different patterns:

One uses:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-N) 'select-next-window)
```

The other one:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-N") 'select-next-window)
```

What's the difference between them? Don't they both define "global" keyboard shortcuts in Emacs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be much of a difference in the major case:

- `(global-set-key key command)` boils down to `(define-key (current-global-map) key command))`, and
- `describe-var` tells us that `global-map` "is a keymap which is usually (but not necessarily) Emacs's global map", whereas
- `(current-global-map)` "returns the current global keymap".

However, [the Emacs docs](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Keymaps.html) talk of "the" global keymap, so it's unclear how, if ever, you can come across several global keymaps.

Comment: The variable `global-map` might be bound to a file or buffer local value, or it could even be bound in a `let` statement.

Comment: The global keymap is set by `use-global-map`. There aren't many packages that do this: mostly a few emulation modes such as Viper, and some functions such as `read-char` that override the global map temporarily.